# Nested Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is this even possible?  I have a logic application that is an unit of functionality (mixture of card connectors and API apps I created) that I would like to share among other logic apps.  From what I can see, this doesn't appear to be allowed.  If this is not possible, I am going to have to recreate the same cards in the logic apps I need this unit of functionality in.

Comment: I am going to give the answer to Carlos as it looks like he has a concrete process.  Though I haven't reviewed it or the answer from Ben yet.  If a review changes this, I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely factor your Logic Apps in smaller flows that can be orchestrated and with the support of conditions and iterations you can do lots of powerful stuff.

Unfortunately today it is not as straight forward to leverage the "Action of Type Workflow" that we have in the system since the User Interface does not expose the capabilities you would want such as adding actions of type Workflow, editing the access keys, and the outputs.

I wrote a quick blog here that shows you how you can do that today using the ARMClient to edit the access keys and make it work:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2015/05/31/using-nested-azure-logic-apps-or-invoking-flows-from-another-logic-app.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my notes from the [Logic Apps talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK1450) at Ignite I wrote that it is possible to nest logic apps.  I don't have an example handy, but it might be worth skimming through the slides/video from that talk.